# How to allocate more cpu usage to a program

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I am running only one program on my computer to crunch numbers, and it takes up about 25% CPU (all other built-in applications are less than 4% CPU). Since this is the only program I am running, how do I raise the CPU percentage from 25% to 40%? I know changing the priority doesn't really help that much, or the affinity. I am using Windows 10. Thanks for help!

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have? Could it be 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distributing a demanding computational task (aka number crunching) among multiple processors or cores is usually not a trivial challenge. Likelihood of success depends upon how easy it is to divide the problem into sub-problems, each of which either doesn't need to communicate with each other or need a sufficiently small amount of communication such that communication overhead does not spoil all the speed gain you theoretically could get by using multiple processors.

Being as it is, this is usually a case-by-case decision. If you are lucky there is a special library for your problem domain for you ready to use.

Examples of problems that lend themselves to parallelization (quite) well are

- video encoding (different time sections are practically independent of each other and can be encoded separately)
- fractals like Mandelbrot (any area of the fractal is completely independent of the others)
- explicit structural mechanics equations like crash solvers (solution volumes interact only across surface boundaries, so some communication between processors is necessary, but not much)

Examples of things that don't go so well with parallelization:

- dense matrix inversion (maximum dependence of each component from every other component)
- implicit structural mechanics equations, like nonlinear equilibrium solution (requires matrix inversion to solve, so same problem as before)

Answer (score 0):

You (probably) can't do that.

The reason that you cannot do that is probably that the program you run is [*Single-Threaded*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Single_threading) and you have a [Quad-Core-Processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor). 25% is a quarter of a whole (processor). This means that one core of your Four-Core-Processor is fully used - resulting in a 25% usage.

Unless you can make your software *Multi-Threaded* (that means using multiple cores parallely) you are stuck with this limit.